# Tunneling traffic from socks5 proxy to VPN tun

Tags: iptables, vpn, iproute

I have the following setup:

```
                        ______________________________
                       |                              |
                       |            Client            |
                       |______________________________|
                                       |
                                       | 
                                       |
                   __  ________________|_______________
                  |   |        Caddy Webserver         | subroute -> reverse proxied to a socks5 proxy
                  |   |       (listening on 443)       |_____________________________
                  |   |________________________________|                             |
                  |                    |                                             |
                  |                    |                                             |
                  |                    |                                             |
      VPS (Ubuntu)|                    |                                             |
                  |                    |                             ________________|_______________
                  |                    |                            |          socks5 proxy          |
                  |                    |                            | (listening on localhost:10000) |
                  |                    |                            |      (running under user1)     |
                  |                    |                            |________________|_______________|
                  |                    |                                             |
                  |___                 |                                             |
                                       |                                             |
                                       |                                             |
                                       |                                             |
                                       |_____________________ _______________________|
                                                            / \
                                                           /   \
                                                        the internet
```

This setup works at the moment, but I wish to adjust it to work in the following way:

```
                  ______________________________
                 |                              |
                 |            Client            |
                 |______________________________|
                                 |
                                 |
            ||===================|=====================================================================|| 
            ||   ________________|_______________                                                      ||
            ||  |        Caddy Webserver         | subroute -> reverse proxied to a socks5 proxy       ||
            ||  |       (listening on 443)       |_____________________________                        ||
            ||  |________________________________|                             |                       ||
            ||                   |                                             |                       ||
VPS (Ubuntu)||                   |                                             |                       ||
            ||                   |                             ________________|_______________        ||
            ||                   |                            |          socks5 proxy          |       ||
            ||                   |                            | (listening on localhost:10000) |       ||
            ||                   |                            |      (running under user1)     |       ||
            ||                   |                            |________________ _______________|       ||
            ||                   |                                             |                       ||
            ||                   |                             ________________|_______________        ||
            ||                   |                            |          proprietary VPN       |       ||
            ||                   |                            |      (using tun0 interface)    |       ||
            ||                   |                            |________________ _______________|       ||
            ||                   |                                             |                       ||
            |====================|=============================================|=======================||
                                 |                                             |
                                 |                             ________________|_______________
                                 |                            |     VPN Service Server         |
                                / \                           |________________|_______________|
                               /   \                                           |
                            the internet                                      / \ 
                                                                             /   \
                                                                        the internet
```

In this second scenario, the SOCKS5 server and the VPN client is on the same server.

I have the SOCKS5 server running through a specific user, so that I can possibly just reroute all traffic from that user. But I'm not sure of how to do that at all.

From my understanding I should be able to create routes or IP Tables rules to forward all traffic from one user to a specified interface (tun0).

Is this possible? And how can this be done? Please provide me with some direction as the IP tables rules and routing rules I've seen so far doesn't make much sense to me as I rarely use these tools.

Edit:
I've updated the diagrams to give some more details of the complete setup.

Everything in the Ubuntu VPS I have full control over. The incoming traffic that I want to route through the VPN can only come through the Caddy -> reverse_proxy -> proxy server route. I just want to further tunnel it through the VPN.

Comment: I'm missing some detail in your question. Why not just let the server access anything on the internet through the VPN? Do you want **only** proxy traffic to go through the VPN and nothing else?

Comment: Yes, I want only the proxied traffic to go through the VPN. If I am completely wrong in my approach, I am also open to other suggestions.

Comment: Not wrong, just more difficult. The easier thing is to use the VPN as the default gateway. But that's not what you want ;-)

Comment: Finding it super fun to make ASCII diagrams. Updated it to show more details of the situation.

Comment: Well now that I think about it, if I were to make the VPN the default gateway, it means that traffic in my diagram above that just goes straight down to the internet would go through the VPN right? I guess that's not ideal, but I might as well test if it'll work well enough. This is where my knowledge falls short though. How would that influence the incoming traffic to the Caddy Webserver?

Comment: yes. You can keep a static route for the CIDR range of your VPC (cloud network). That way only internet headed traffic goes through the vpn.